# Refreshing cookie ticket in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using .NET Core and OpenID Connect, with cookie configured with `SlidingExpiration = true` and `ExpireTimeSpan = 20 minutes`.

What I observe is that while I am working on task in the application and not knowing the cookie's ticket has expire due to the `ExpireTimeSpan`. The application will not execute any function example: prompting me that time is about the expire or log me out.

What I understand so far is that `SlidingExpiration` should provide me with a new ticket if they refresh the page 10 mints or so, but what I notice it is otherwise.

So I wonder is there anyway I can get the cookie's ticket renew before the expire and the task/process should be transparent to me. What I notice in `CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs` there is a cool function call `OnCheckSlidingExpiration`. I am wondering how should I use that function in my current application.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source codes, I found the OnCheckSlidingExpiration method is called by the CookieAuthenticationHandler's CheckForRefreshAsync method.

The source codes of the CheckForRefreshAsync  method is like below:

```
    private async Task CheckForRefreshAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var currentUtc = Clock.UtcNow;
        var issuedUtc = ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc;
        var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        var allowRefresh = ticket.Properties.AllowRefresh ?? true;
        if (issuedUtc != null && expiresUtc != null && Options.SlidingExpiration && allowRefresh)
        {
            var timeElapsed = currentUtc.Subtract(issuedUtc.Value);
            var timeRemaining = expiresUtc.Value.Subtract(currentUtc);

            var eventContext = new CookieSlidingExpirationContext(Context, Scheme, Options, ticket, timeElapsed, timeRemaining)
            {
                ShouldRenew = timeRemaining < timeElapsed,
            };
            await Options.Events.OnCheckSlidingExpiration(eventContext);

            if (eventContext.ShouldRenew)
            {
                RequestRefresh(ticket);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to write your own logic for refresh cookie token, I suggest you could try to rewrite this hanlder.

More details about how to rewrite this method, you could refer to this [article](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-cookieauthenticationmiddleware-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: Yes, what is what I read too. But this is only for .net 6 (unless I'm wrong). 

I also read the link that you provided too but seems like it is alot of work for a mature software which I'm worried that I make break something.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile and I forget to reply my answer.

I've solve my issue using ajax script:

1. set an interval of x number of seconds before the cookie expire and once the the time is up, call the function.
2. the function shall open another small window(to do the refresh) and then close the small window
3. The cookies has refreshed!

Example of the ajax script:

setInterval(function () { redirectRefreshSessionPage(); }, 900000); //set interval as every 15mins

```
    function redirectRefreshSessionPage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{uri for refresh window}",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "html"
    })
        .done(
            function (data) {
                let options = { focus: false, keyboard: true };
                $("#sessionModalWrapper").html(data);
                $('#refresh page modal').modal(options);
                $('#refresh page modal').modal('show');
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is fairly old now but adding in my own answer as I spent a fair amount of time trying to work out something similar and feel it could be helpful. In .NET 6 you can override the default cookie authentication event methods, one of those is the one mentioned OnCheckSlidingExpiration. You'll want to update this in your project's Program.cs file, I personally did it when configuring the application cookie like so:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnCheckSlidingExpiration = context =>
    {
        var path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        context.ShouldRenew = context.ElapsedTime > (context.Options.ExpireTimeSpan / 2);

        if (path == "/PathWeDontWantToRenewExpiration")
        {
            context.ShouldRenew = false;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

It's important to include what the default functionality for updating the cookie expiry as otherwise the expiry won't update at all, in this code i'm basically saying "It should renew if the elapsed time is over half of the expire time span, unless the call is being made to '/PathWeDontWantToRenewExpiration'".

I also found some examples in the .NET Core GitHub Repo: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/samples/CookieSample/Program.cs